# How to run selenium tests on VM without active RDP?

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, rdp

I have a certain number of Selenium tests on Python and a Google Cloud VM with the ability to connect via RDP.

I want to be able to run the tests without an active RDP session. Currently, when I try to run automation with a closed session, I receive an error because there is no display (it's clearly visible when trying to take a screenshot of the screen - it works with an active session, but not with an inactive one).

**I tried already:**

- I have tried creating a virtual display, but it doesn't help.
- I also tried opening an RDP session to the machine using RDP 2 and then closing the RDP 2 session, but that didn't help either.

**The additional info:**
When I'm trying the same approach with Java-based selenium all works well and awt screenshots work well too.
I don't understand **why Java-based Selenium tests worked well without an active RDP session, but Python-based didn't**

How can I bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to do exactly what you are asking but I have tried to do something similar - ie, run Python-automated stuff on Windows without needing to be logged in to Remote Desktop all the time, and although I'm not sure I've entirely solved it, perhaps this will help. I did this:

1. Create second account on target machine (if one does not exist already)
2. Install TightVNC on the target machine (the one I want to RDP into), set up to connect to RDP sessions.
3. Install a VNC viewer on the machine I want to RDP FROM, probably doesn't matter which one but I used RemoteRipple as it's also free and lightweight.
4. Log in to remote machine using the usual Windows RDP interface, but to a different account to the target one, maybe the one created in Step 1.
5. Connect via VNC - although actually I don't think it matters much if you connect earlier and just leave it open. The VNC window now should show the usual Windows logon screen - and you should be able to use it to log in to the account that you actually want to log in to. At this point, the RDP session will prompt you to disconnect as another user is attempting to login - and when it disconnects the VNC connection will stay active, and you can disconnect and reconnect to it at will, seemingly without affecting the running of Clicknium automation in my case, although I'm sure Selenium is the same.

Again, it's not an ideal solution I don't think, but hopefully will work well enough for now.